# Schedule task on window's Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I want create scheduler Task on windows. I want to run this task daily.It should be start at 6:00 AM and stop at 2:25 PM and repeat it in every 5 mins. After 2:25 PM task stop and start 2:35 PM again with 5 mins of interval . ( 10 mins for other scripts )

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to create three separate tasks (if you really want it this way) for this. Just set the *Trigger* to start at 6am, repeat every 5min, end 2.25am.
Second task triggers 2.25 (your other scripts) and ends 2.35. 
Third task triggers 2.35 and repeats every 5min. 
hope this helps!

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Phils , How can I stop task at  2:25 PM daily ..?

Comment: You can create the end of the task within the Trigger menu.

Comment: Can you please provide some details regarding how to end task .. it is new for me . Thanks